# Reordering array of images animates images order on screen

Tags: jquery, css

I have a bunch of images in an array that are shown on the screen. When I sort the array I would like the images on the screen to transition to their new sorted position.

I'm not sure how to approach the movement animation of the images. I was thinking about using `transition` in css and `.position()` in jquery but the `li` element don't change position.

How could go about moving the images with an animation or transition effect?

Comment: If you dont mind using a plugin you can check Quicksand https://razorjack.net/quicksand/

Comment: That's the result I want but I can't seem to get it to work. Thanks for showing me that.